# How to share photos from iOS as JPG with EXIF?

Tags: iphone, photos, metadata

I want to share photos with friends in JPG, but need to keep its metadata (time taken, GPS coordinates...) in EXIF.

I tried to send them via web-based filesharing service. JPGs was uploaded, but all metadata was stripped off. Same when I tried to convert photos to JPG using Copy&Paste trick (copy photos in gallery, paste in Files).

All what I'm able to do is share photos to files (it creates HEIVC files there) and then convert them in PC using [FonePaw HEIC Converter](https://www.fonepaw.com/heic-converter/).

I think there must be easier way. Maybe some shortcut? Thanks for help!

Comment: "via web-based filesharing service" - there's the problem. Many of them strip metadata for privacy.  I suppose you could zip them - though you would save no data space & the files may indeed be slightly larger. [I have no idea how to zip a file in iOS, though :/

Comment: I don't know if it changes any behavior of EXIF so I leave a comment here: There's a setting called *format*. It changes default format of photo that you taken to jpeg - It's located under Settings -> Camera -> Formats -> Most Compatible(default is High Efficiency).

Comment: @Tetsujin No, the filesharing service is not modify them, checked. It's iOS feature, according what I read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57942150/file-upload-and-exif-in-mobile-safari

Comment: @Skye-AT This does not help with images already taken :). Also I think there is no automatic JPG in Most  Compatible settings. I don't have iPhone, so can't test now, but this setting was set there and still HEIVC was served to me.

Comment: Regarding Tetsujin's suggestion: You can compress photo into zip! Select photo(s) in Photos app, and once you've selected photos, hit share button(located bottom left of screen if you're using iPhone). Then, select Save to Files, and save wherever you want(I suggest creating folder under iCloud or on your device so it's easier to locate). Long press that folder(if you've created) and hit compress, it'll create zip file. Or tap "..." button, tap Select, and select photo(s) and tap "..." button, then tap compress.

Comment: @Lluser That's strange. All my photos I took is in jpg format with this settings... hmm

Comment: @Skye-AT maybe I'm wrong. I'll have access to an iPhone on weekend, so I'll check it again. But still want to know solution how to export JPG with properly populated EXIF when photos were taken in HEIVC...

Comment: You can create a shortcut to convert HEIC to JPG while keeping metadata

Comment: Social media sites such as Facebook and Instagram will strip metadata.  File sharing sites such as Dropbox and Google drive do not strip metadata.